# Dimension of a vector space of polynomials in 3 variables of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space of homogeneous polynomials in 3 variables $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> What is $\dim V$?

I think it will be some expression in terms of $d$ but I am not sure how to find the answer

Comment: you perhaps mean degree at most $d$, otherwise this cannot be vector space, as you cannot have a zero vector.

Comment: No, I am only considering degree equal to $d$

Comment: Well in that case $V$ is not a vector space. Look at the polynomials
$x_1x_2x_3$ and $-x_1x_2x_3 + x_1^2$. Both are of degree $3$ but their sum is not

Comment: If you see my original post, I have attached the corresponding question-it says vector space of degree d

Comment: ah it says homogeneous! That changes everything now

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. I didn't compute it explicitly, but i hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you :) how does the homogeneous condition change things?

Comment: homogeneous means that not just the polynomials but also all monomials must be of degree $d$. So for example if $d=3$ then $V$ does not contain $-x_1x_2x_3+x_1^2$. You still need to assume $V$ also contains $0$ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monomials $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}x_3^{d_3}$ with $d_1+d_2+d_3=d$ form a basis of $V$. By the [Stars and Bars Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) there are ${d+2\choose2}$ such monomials. It follows that ${\rm dim}(V)={d+2\choose 2}$.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'stars and bars'?

Answer (score 0):

A basis for $V$ will be the following set:
$$\{x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k : i+j+k=d\}$$

So what you looking is essentially number of different partitions of $d$ using 3 natural numbers (called a restricted partition). I think the following wikipedia page includes the answer to that 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)